# Tensorflow image classifier accuracy

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, scikit-learn, imagenet

I just followed [this great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSKfRcEDGUs) about how to quickly retrain ImageNet and make image classifiers using Tensorflow. I made the classifier, and it works well. From what I understand, Tensorflow partitions the provided dataset into training, test and validation by itself - or at least it does with this script. I've worked with sklearn in the past, and you can always find the accuracy of the model.

My question is, how can I find the accuracy percentage of the trained model in Tensorflow, specifically for image classifiers?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Nevermind I got it - it is displayed after the last step after the test set has been cycled through.